# ASP.NET Web API 2.0 Parameters Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I know it's been asked a lot of time and I have tried everything but still facing the problem. Here is my code:

```
    // POST api/<controller>
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

There is nothing fancy just returning the value.
I am using Chrome's PostMan Plugin
I have tried like 100 times but still getting the same null value as the response. I have tried it with Content-Type application/json and everything mentioned but still getting null.

Comment: Well, how are you calling it?  The problem is obviously not in the code you posted.

Comment: Show us what you're sending as well.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved the problem was in the object I was sending.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the question is however what you are looking for is to setup your `POST` with a single value.

Such as below:

```
POST /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50121
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json, text/javascript
Cache-Control: no-cache

'abc'
```

Now this is a `JSON` post so the body doesn't have a parameter name, this is by design as you are posting a single value.

If you need multiple values or a more complex object you should use a `class` object instead of a single value.
[image: Headers][image: Body]

Comment: I don't think that accept will solve the issue  accept is used to tell the server send me response in this form

Comment: `Accept` doesnt solve it. However the `Content-Type` and the setup of the request body does. The `Accept` header will help Web Api determine the result of the call. Again in this case has no bearing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

Comment: Thank you so much. As all the questions on StackOverflow were about complex json, it was getting very difficult for me to understand how to send a simple string. I was doing this 
{
  value: "Hello World"
}

instead of "Hello World"

Comment: Yeah its a bit tricky to understand the single value string. Make sure you mark the answers if you are satisfied. Regards.